# Python Microservices with Nameko

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, nameko

I'm trying to follow the simple [Python Microservices with Nameko](https://www.toptal.com/python/introduction-python-microservices-nameko) example.

I have both rabbitmq and rabbitmq management running in dockers:

> docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
>
> docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name mgmt-rabbit -p 15672:15672
> rabbitmq:3-management

I can browse to http://localhost:15672 and it's running.

I have installed nameko by using:

> pip install nameko

Created my virtualenv and created helloworld.py:

```
# helloworld.py

from nameko.rpc import rpc

class GreetingService:
    name = "greeting_service"

    @rpc
    def hello(self, name):
        return "Hello, {}!".format(name)
```

If I run any of these commands:

> nameko run helloworld
>
> nameko run helloworld:GreetingService
>
> nameko run helloworld --broker amqp://guest:guest@localhost

I get this error:

> Error: No module named 'helloworld'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When python looks for a module , it will look at  `__init__.py` in  your directory , you must check you have `__init__.py` file in your helloworld.py directory  .